# Is it good to outsource SQL queries into own module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, module

At the moment i am practicing with SQLite and i do a lot of this:

```
con = lite.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("INSERT INTO cars VALUES(1,'Audi',52642)")

con.commit()
```

Now after i understood some of the basics i ask myself what is the best way to write a programm with a lot of SQL Queries? DO you guys outsource them into an own Module? Are there any good tutotials?

Background of my question is:

1. I do this con = lite.connect('test.db') in every module. So if the DB changes i have to change it in every module. So whats the best practice to do this?
2. Also i have some dublicates of queries in different modules. If they were in their on module i could just reuse them. Is this a common or recommended way?

Comment: Use a single database connection for the life of the process, passing it around as an argument to functions where needed.

Comment: @Shawn could you give an example for this? Thank you!